# Is there a difference between return new type and returning an object?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Within C#, is there any difference in the byte code that is generated for the two different ways of writing, what i expect to be the same thing:

Return Created Object:

```
public MemoryStream GetStream() {
  MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(this.GetBytes());
  return s;
}
```

Return New:

```
public MemoryStream GetStream() {
  return new MemoryStream(this.GetBytes());
}
```

Will any differences be optimised away? Or is the first more susceptible to garbage collection than the second? Or is this all just personal preference?

Comment: I suppose, it is personal preference. I don't see what optimization can be made of this code.

Comment: The compiler will inline the entire method anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the IL code, it seems that there are less steps in the second version than the first.

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x22c0
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream CS$1$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: stloc.1
    IL_0009: br.s IL_000b

    IL_000b: ldloc.1
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Form1::GetStream1

.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x22dc
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream CS$1$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: br.s IL_0009

    IL_0009: ldloc.0
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method Form1::GetStream2
```

It doesnt seem like its doing a hell of a lot more, but a few more steps none the less.

@Alexei Levenkov, This is the Release version of the code

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2264
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method Form1::GetStream1

.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2278
    // Code size 6 (0x6)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
    IL_0005: ret
} // end of method Form1::GetStream2
```

Still seems slightly more.

Comment: Are you sure it is not non-optimized IL (from debug build)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Reflector to inspect the code generated for this:

```
public MemoryStream GetStream(byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    return s;
}
```

For release builds you get this:

```
.method public hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream(uint8[] bytes) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s)
    L_0000: ldarg.1 
    L_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor(uint8[])
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: ldloc.0 
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

So as you can see, the C# compiler has optimised away the extra variable.

However, for a debug build you get this:

```
.method public hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream GetStream(uint8[] bytes) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor(uint8[])
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: stloc.1 
    L_000a: br L_000f
    L_000f: ldloc.1 
    L_0010: ret 
}
```

Obviously the compiler can't optimise away the extra variable for debug build, in case you want to inspect it while debugging.

So if you want to leave the extra variable in for debugging purposes, then it's fine - it will have no effect on a release build.

Comment: But doesn't the optimizer inline it in release build when you call GetStream so it will look like the method doesn't even exist. At least this happens quite often when looking stack tracers with such helper methods.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen The JIT compiler might do so, but of course the C# compiler will not do so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe resulting optimized JITed code will be identical.

There is definitely no impact on GC behavior as lifetime of object will be determined by whoever uses return value (you may be thinking about case when value is no longer used before end of function which is clearly not the case here - `s` is returned right at the end of execution of the method).

The only noticeable difference in non-optimized (debug) build you'll be able to see value of `s` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The two code-snippets are ***mostly*** identical with little performance difference which is negligible and it is a matter of code-style and method functionality to choose from them.
If your method is not supposed to do anything else other than returning the `MemoryStream` object, then the second code-snippet would suffice, but if you need to perform some operations on the `MemoryStream` object prior to returning it, the first one must be used.
There is no difference in terms of Garbage Collection.